# What should I use instead of index in a key for an array in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, eslintrc

I have the below code:

```
const array1 = [23, 50, 63, 90, 10, 30, 155, 23, 18];
const array2 = [133, 60, 23, 92, 6, 7, 168, 16, 19];
const array3 = [30, 43, 29, 10, 50, 40, 99, 51, 12];
```

and

```
<TableRow>
              { array1.map((item, index) => <TableRowColumn data-test-id={`array-item-1-${index}`} key={index}>{item}</TableRowColumn>)}
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              { array2.map((item, index) => <TableRowColumn data-test-id={`array-item-2-${index}`} key={index}>{item}</TableRowColumn>)}
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
              { array3.map((item, index) => <TableRowColumn data-test-id={`array-item-3-${index}`} key={index}>{item}</TableRowColumn>)}
           </TableRow>
```

I'm getting an error saying -Do not use Array index in keys (react/no-array-index-key).

What should I use instead of **index** or how should I solve this issue?

Let me know if you require more details.

Comment: If the elements in the array have no unique qualifier, and inserting or deleting elements somewhere other than the end of the array is not intended, you can use the index, and just disable the linter warning. Otherwise, generate some identifier, e.g. by a running number, uuid, etc.

Comment: Why not using the same value you have for `data-test-id`? That should make the keys unique and the linter happy.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I have disabled the linter warning. Thanks!

Comment: Just to re-iterate, the **and**-part is not for show. If you are inserting/deleting somewhere else than the end of the array (or deleteting and inserting at the same time, or probably some edge case i forgot), and have index as key, weird things will happen. In some cases that just never happens (e.g. static array, never changes), and only then is index as key ok. React will even take index as key per default iirc, so in these cases, the `key` attribute can just be omitted.